# What might cause a splunk lookup table to suddenly show no rows?

Tags: splunk

One of my new colleagues was working on a lookup in a splunk app and seems to have somehow made a lookup table unavailable.  His task involved creating and uploading a lookup csv, creating a lookup definition and creating an automatic lookup.  No one else has been modifying this Splunk App.

An existing lookup started no longer populating in a dashboard. I looked at the “datasets” and the lookup csv exists and shows a last modified date from way before this issue started, but no rows display when I click on it.

I’m at a loss for what could have caused this or how to fix this.  It seems the data still exists, as the modified date hasn’t changed, but somehow has become inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues where you need to check with lookups.

Check the permissions on the lookup CSV file, and also the lookup declaration. What app was the lookup file and lookup declaration defined in, and was it made available to all apps, or just the app it was defined in? Try typing `| inputlookup filename.csv` and `| inputlookup lookupname` to see if they have data, if they return nothing, or if Splunk gives an error saying file not found. It's it possible they did an `| outputloookup` or `| outputcsv` and overwrote the data that had been uploaded?